# R how tocheck if a data table column is all zeros

Tags: r, data.table, zero

I would like to remove the columns that have all zeros.  But, some of the columns appear to have non numeric values.   How can I remove the non numeric columns, and the columns with all zeros.  It would be helpful if the non numeric column name was printed, or the column number, so I can determine if it was ok to remove the column.

Here's what I'm trying, but it doesn't work when the data table has non numeric values.

```
removeColsAllZeros = function(ddt) {
  m <- as.matrix(ddt)
  # isNumericColList <- lapply(1:ncol(m), function(ii,mm){is.numeric(mm[,ii])}, mm=m)
  # indexNonNumericCols <- which(!unlist(isNumericColList))
  mnz <- m[, colSums(abs(m),na.rm = TRUE) != 0]
  return(mnz)
}
```

Comment: `unique(Col) ==  0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the other answers were helpful, but they didn't totally answer the question.  Here's a function with to identify and remove the non-numeric and all zero columns from a data table.  This was helpful and provided additional insight into the data set.

```
removeColsAllZeros = function(ddt) {
  # Identify and remove nonnumeric cols and cols with all zeros
  idx_all_zeros = ddt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){ (is.numeric(x) & all(x==0))  })]
  idx_not_numeric = ddt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){ (!is.numeric(x))  })]
  idx_all_zeros = which(unlist(idx_all_zeros))
  idx_not_numeric = which(unlist(idx_not_numeric))
  # Print bad column names
  if (length(idx_all_zeros)>0) {
    cat('Numeric columns with all zeros are\n',paste(names(ddt)[idx_all_zeros],collapse='\n'),'\n')
    flush.console()
  }
  if (length(idx_not_numeric)>0) {
    cat('Nonnumeric columns are\n',paste(names(ddt)[idx_not_numeric],collapse='\n'),'\n')
    flush.console()
  }
  # Determine the numeric columns that have nonzero values
  idx_bad = union(idx_all_zeros, idx_not_numeric)
  idx_good = setdiff(seq(1,ncol(ddt)), idx_bad)
  # Return nonzero numeric data
  ddt[, .SD, .SDcols = idx_good]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple function that can be applied to all columns in your data frame, returning just the ones that are numeric and not all zero:

```
# Fake data 
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(5), 
             y=rep(0,5), 
             z=sample(c(1,0),5,replace=TRUE),
             w=sample(LETTERS[1:3],5,replace=TRUE),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat
           x y z w
1  0.5450570 0 0 B
2  0.5292899 0 0 B
3 -0.2142306 0 1 C
4 -0.7246841 0 0 C
5 -0.7567683 0 1 A

# Remove columns with all zeros or that are not numeric
dat[, !sapply(names(dat), function(col) {all(dat[,col]==0) | 
                                           !is.numeric(dat[,col])})]

           x z
1  0.5450570 0
2  0.5292899 0
3 -0.2142306 1
4 -0.7246841 0
5 -0.7567683 1
```

To unpack this, the function checks, for a single column of `dat`, whether it has all zeros or is not numeric. `sapply` then "applies" this function to every column in the data frame, returning a logical vector with `TRUE` for columns of `dat` with all zeros or that are non-numeric, and `FALSE` for columns that are numeric and not all zeros. The `!` ("NOT") before `sapply` just reverses the `FALSE` and `TRUE` values:

```
!sapply(names(dat), function(col) {
  all(dat[, col]==0) | !is.numeric(dat[, col])
  })

   x     y     z     w 
TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Then we use this logical vector to return only those columns of `dat` that are `TRUE`.

```
dat[ , c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]

           x z
1  0.5450570 0
2  0.5292899 0
3 -0.2142306 1
4 -0.7246841 0
5 -0.7567683 1
```

Finally, to check the non-numeric columns that were removed, do the following, which will return all non-numeric columns:

```
dat[, sapply(names(dat), function(col) {!is.numeric(dat[,col])})]
```

Comment: Very clear explanation. I am learning data.table now, and I would like to ask a question. I converted dat to data.table. `setDT(dat)[,!sapply(names(dat), function(col) {all(dat[,col]==0) |!is.numeric(dat[,col])})]`. This returns a logical vector including FALSE only. This is probably a simple question, but I would like to know why this happened. Thank you.

Comment: How should this approach be modified to work for data tables also?

Comment: @jazzurro: data.table returns a *column name* when you do `dat[, col]`, because col is a string. You can do `dat[, col, with=FALSE]` to use the string as a column name, and this returns a column, so your `all(dat[,col]==0)` will work, but it returns the column as a *list*, not a vector, so `is.numeric(dat[,col])` fails. You can use `is.numeric(unlist(dat[,col,with=FALSE], use.names=FALSE))` instead. Not sure how efficient this is though, and I'd be interested to know if there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: @naught101 Thank you very much for your message for an old comment. I am happy to see this explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not compact but works on data table after modifying @eipi10's code.

```
# toy data
set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(5), 
                 y=rep(0,5), 
                 z=sample(c(1,0),5,replace=TRUE),
                 w=sample(LETTERS[1:3],5,replace=TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# code for a data table
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
idx = sapply(dat, function(x){ !(all(x==0) | !is.numeric(x)) })
dat[, .SD, .SDcols = idx]
#             x z
# 1: -0.6264538 1
# 2:  0.1836433 1
# 3: -0.8356286 0
# 4:  1.5952808 1
# 5:  0.3295078 0
```

Comment: Thank you, I need a data table solution.  I will to wait till tomorrow to evaluate this solution with data.  I still need the column indices of the all zero or non numeric columns, which may be idxout <- !(idx %in% seq(1,ncol(dat))).  The data table has about 1200 columns, and I need to determine where the non numeric columns are coming from.